# java.lang.VerifyError: Bad local variable type by deploying war file

Tags: java, tomcat, war

I am working on a tomcat8 Netbeans-Project using java-8 and I can't get it to work on my machine.
If I try to run it in netbeans I get :

```
    05-Feb-2020 10:41:57.180 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-16] org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResourcesImpl.cleanUp Failed to retrieve JNDI naming context for container [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/projectnameServer]] so no cleanup was performed for that container
    javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [comp/env] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [comp].
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:833)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResourcesImpl.cleanUp(NamingResourcesImpl.java:1021)
        at org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResourcesImpl.stopInternal(NamingResourcesImpl.java:1003)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5410)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.undeploy(ManagerServlet.java:1521)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:381)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:666)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:348)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1598)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
05-Feb-2020 10:41:57.696 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-16] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeploy Undeploying context [/projectnameServer]
05-Feb-2020 10:41:57.754 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-14] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying deployment descriptor [/home/myuser/Downloads/apache-tomcat-9.0.30/conf/Catalina/localhost/projectnameServer.xml]
05-Feb-2020 10:41:57.756 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-14] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor The path attribute with value [/projectnameServer] in deployment descriptor [/home/myuser/Downloads/apache-tomcat-9.0.30/conf/Catalina/localhost/projectnameServer.xml] has been ignored
05-Feb-2020 10:41:57.759 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-14] org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule.begin [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'antiJARLocking' to 'true' did not find a matching property.
05-Feb-2020 10:41:57.916 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-14] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Error deploying deployment descriptor [/home/myuser/Downloads/apache-tomcat-9.0.30/conf/Catalina/localhost/projectnameServer.xml]
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:720)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:631)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:487)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1642)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:289)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:809)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1590)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:1019)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:355)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:666)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:348)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1598)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/projectnameServer]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
        ... 41 more
    Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad local variable type
Exception Details:
  Location:
    tl/subl/projectname/hessian/util/AuthenticatedServlet.<clinit>()V @0: aload_0
  Reason:
    Type top (current frame, locals[0]) is not assignable to reference type
  Current Frame:
    bci: @0
    flags: { }
    locals: { }
    stack: { }
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 2abb 0004 59b7 0005 b900 0602 0057 2ab9
    0000010: 0007 0100 b300 08b1                    

        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:3062)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:2249)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:110)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:269)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:137)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:69)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:330)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:777)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:301)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5051)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 42 more
05-Feb-2020 10:41:57.918 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-14] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of deployment descriptor [/home/myuser/Downloads/apache-tomcat-9.0.30/conf/Catalina/localhost/projectnameServer.xml] has finished in [164] ms
```

The projects is a java-webstart-project and has two other project as foreign-projects configured.
For the build process ant is used.
The app connects to a postgresql database using hibernate and tomcat-jdbc pooling.

I already tried using the tomcat installed in my (linux) system, a fresh donwloaded apache-tomcat-8.5.50 and apache-tomcat-9.0.30, it all ends up the same.
**But** it is working in a docker-container using this.

```
FROM tomcat:8.5.50-jdk8-openjdk

ADD dist/app.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/app.war

ADD postgresql-42.2.9.jar /usr/local/tomcat/lib/postgresql-42.2.9.jar
```

Do you have an idea what to do because it is very painfull building the docker-container after every change and so I am not able to debug the application.

Thx for your help.

Comment: Please describe the Java tools you're using. This error usually means that there was post-compile processing of the class files that had a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very unsatisfying answer, updated the netbeans java-nb-plugin it worked.